# Undefined Control Sequence in Overleaft Template for IEEE Transactions

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, overleaf

I'm writing an article for IEEE transactions using overleaf. I'm using algorithm and algorithmic to create a algorithm in my template, but the `UNDEFINED CONTROL SEQUENCE` error appears. Below the code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
        \usepackage{mathabx}
        \usepackage{algorithm}
        \usepackage{algorithmic}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{mdwmath}
        \usepackage{mdwtab}
        \usepackage{eqparbox}
        \usepackage{url}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Basic Algorithm}\label{basic}
    \begin{algorithmic}  
        \for{i = 1 : nBytes}
                \State $dataEBC = aes_encrypt_function(data(i),key)$
                \State $modSignal = step (hMod, dataEBC)$
                \State $noisySignal = step(hAWGN, modSignal)$
                \State $receivedData = step(hDemod, noisySignal)$
                \State $statedec(i) = aes_decrypt_function(receivedData, key)$
            \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Where is into the preamble `\documentclass[...]{...}`?

Comment: your example is missing the `\documentclass` line so we can not run it, and you haven't shown the error messge that says which command is undefined so it is hard to help

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited the post.

Comment: Use capital letters for `\STATE`, `\FOR`, and `\ENDFOR`.

Comment: Thanks. Have you resolved with the help of @Ilbant?

Comment: Try to add `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Now it worked but the line numbers for the algorithm in IEEE templates doesn't appear. I'm going to try to solve this.

Comment: If you use`algcompatible` package, then there is no need for the capital `\STATE` etc I suggested above. To get the line numbers, add `\begin{algorithmic}[1]`. @Sebastiano, maybe modify your answer for a clear solution.

Comment: Now I can't @Ilbant. Can You add an answer and I remove my answer?

Comment: @Ilbant Excuse me for my delay. In this morning I have not many times. Now I have changed my code. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with `pdflatex` and run it. Many thanks to @Ilbant and @DavidCarslie for your precious helps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
        \usepackage{mathabx}
        \usepackage{algorithm}
        \usepackage{algorithmic}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{mdwmath}
        \usepackage{mdwtab}
        \usepackage{eqparbox}
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \caption{Basic Algorithm}\label{basic}
            \FOR{i = 1 : nBytes}
                \STATE $dataEBC = aes_encrypt_function(data(i),key)$
                \STATE $modSignal = step (hMod, dataEBC)$
                \STATE $noisySignal = step(hAWGN, modSignal)$
                \STATE $receivedData = step(hDemod, noisySignal)$
                \STATE $statedec(i) = aes_decrypt_function(receivedData, key)$
            \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: why `[latin1]` ?  (there is no non ascii input so inputenc isn't required at all but if you do use it, for new documents utf8 should usually be preferred to latin1.)

Comment: You're right but with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and Papeeria I have several errors: for example `LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. [    \caption]`.

Comment: You will get that error if you use a caption outside of a float.changing the input encoding will not change an error message about the position of `\caption`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do! Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have changed my code.